# Google Map variable is null

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to get and set my GoogleMap variable using the the following code:

```
 private GoogleMap mMap; 

 mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myMapView)).getMap();

    //MapFragment fm = (MapFragment)     getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myMapView);
    //mMap = fm.getMap();

    Log.e("RideTracking", "Google Map VALUE:"+mMap);

    if (mMap != null) { 
        proxy.setProjection(mMap.getProjection());
    }
```

Here is my XML for this part of the app:

```
<fragment 
      android:id="@+id/myMapView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

For some reason the value of mMap is null and I'm not sure why it is returning null since I have this line of code:

```
mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myMapView)).getMap();
```

Here is what I get for logcat output:

```
05-13 14:09:08.553: E/RideTracking(6415): Google Map VALUE:null
```

Can anybody offer any advice on why the of mMap is null? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you post manifest file?

Comment: are you referring google play services library project in your android map project? check your map key in manifest

Answer (score 0):

If try putting your code in the method `onActivityCreated()`. This could make sure your map is ready.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with the mMap being NULL.

Try adding the following lines of code under the mMap call.

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
GoogleMap map = mapFragment.getMap();
```

It fixed my problem with the NULL issue.

Try looking into the answer in this post

[NullPointerException whilst trying to add polyline/marker to a GoogleMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147176/nullpointerexception-whilst-trying-to-add-polyline-marker-to-a-googlemap)

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are not able to connect to google maps api, have you obtained the key from google and added it to your manifest? See the links below

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html

Follow these instructions and if it still not works post your manifest and the code i will help you, i have worked on maps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and then I found that I forgot to write line

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_direction);`

Then after my map is working fine. So please ensure that you have set you layout before declaring map.